# Results from LINQ with SUM for TimeSpan, GROUP and JOIN

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, group-by, sum

I've following EF model:

[image]

I want to get data in following view:

[image]

In Data entity Time is Timespan with milliseconds. In result, `PlaceInStep` is place between members by `StepId`.

How to make this hard query?

**Edit 1**:

My some code:

```
var query = from data in ctx.Data
                            join member in ctx.Members
                            on data.MemberId equals member.MemberId
                            join team in ctx.Teams
                            on member.TeamId equals team.TeamId
                            group member by member.TeamId into g
                            select new {TeamId = g.Key, TeamName = g.Select(t=>t.Teams.TeamName), TotalTime = ???};
```

Comment: please show some source code... what have you tried ? what is not working ?

Comment: So, I try to write LINQ query, but I not understand how to get SUM for TimeSpan from grouped?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Advice at first. You should not use join in your queries. You have your model with navigation properties, use them instead. You can read Craig Stuntz's [blogpost](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2010/01/13/38525/) about it.

You can select all teams and information about members in inner list. Try this out:

```
var query = ctx.data.ToList().OrderBy(d => d.Time).
            GroupBy(d => d.Members.StepId).
            SelectMany(g => g.Select((d, place) => new { Time = d.Time, Members = d.Members, PlaceInStep = place + 1 })).
            GroupBy(d => d.Members.TeamId).
            Select(g => new 
            {
               TeamId = g.Key, 
               Name = g.Select(d => d.Members.Teams.TeamName).First(),  
               Members = g.Select(d => new {Time = d.Time, PlaceInStep = d.PlaceInStep, MemberName = d.Members.MemberName}),                    
               TotalTime = g.Aggregate(new TimeSpan(), (sum, nextData) => sum.Add(nextData.Time))
            });
```

Comment: I've got error: The method 'First' can only be used as a final query operation. Consider using the method 'FirstOrDefault' in this instance instead.

Comment: With FirstOrDefault I've got:LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.TimeSpan Aggregate[Data,TimeSpan](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[test1.Data], System.TimeSpan, System.Func`3[System.TimeSpan,test1.Data,System.TimeSpan])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: My mistake, i forget what this is linq-to-entities, not linq-to-objects. Simple solution will be performe all operations on middle-tier side. Just write ctx.Data.ToList() instead of just ctx.Data. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Yes it's helps. Thank you!!! And What about of tema members in query?

Comment: Ok, i updated my answer. Try it.

Comment: In last line: TotalTime = g.g.Aggregate(new TimeSpan(), ... - twice g - it is correct?

Comment: Yes, now it is correct thank you!! But PlaceInStep must be place between members in each Step. Thanks.

Comment: Ok. I changed my answer again. I hope this is final answer)

Comment: Thank you Hober! It's work as expected!

Comment: Well, there is a little trouble: If 2 members in same Step (for ex. before 35 year) have same time up to milliseconds they must have same place.

Comment: And in Members arrange members by StepName or StepId and show it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var query = ctx.Data.Join(ctx.Members, d => d.MemberId, m => m.MemberId, (d,m)=>new {data=d, member = m})
                .Join(ctx.Teams, dm=>dm.member.TeamId, t=>t.TeamId, (dm, t)=>new{data=dm.data, member=dm.member, team = t})
                .GroupBy(dmt=>new {dmt.team.TeamId, dmt.team.TeamName})
                .Select(g=>new 
                           {
                               TeamId = g.Key.TeamId, 
                               TeamName = g.Key.TeamName, 
                               TotalTime = g.Aggregate(0, (sum, gr)=>sum.Add(gr.data.Time))
                           });
```

Comment: I've got error: Operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'System.TimeSpan'

Comment: of course. Sorry, in my modelling code it was int. I Update answer with sum.Add()